# Thermaltake VH6000BWS hard drive bay upgrade

Tags: hard-drive, drive-bay

I got the [VH6000BWS](http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/Product.aspx?C=1277&ID=1408) and I have used up all standard 3.5" bays. how can I use the ones in the front? Is there a product to make them usable for Hard drives all in one? Hotswap and that kind of stuff would be nice but is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 options:

You can get HDD "rails" that expand a hard drive out to 5.25" width to allow mounting inside the case.

You can get hard drive drawers that mount like a CD-ROM and take a hard drive in them.

You can get hot-swap RAID bays that take multiple hard drives and take up a number of 5.25" bays.

Try this Google: [5.25 hard drive adapter](http://www.google.com/search?q=5.25+hard+drive+adapter)

Answer (score 0):

I used to use ICYDock a long time ago, they are well known. Check out some products. Note that this is the more expensive but more professional option. www.icydock.com/goods_cat.php?id=50

Then i just found this, a thermaltake rack, http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811999141. Its a 3-drive rack that fits in 5.25" bays. It seems like it was made for users of their cases who ran out of internal HDD slots and want to use the external 5.25 ones like you.
 But its just a rack. 
If you need to change the drives out, you may want to consider a one-drive tray like this one ( i have this one ) http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817998032 Fully supports hot-swap and hot-plug.